# Overscroll Behaviour in Div

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Like you see in the video: https://youtube.com/shorts/-S4e-YvaSXM?feature=share a bounce scrolling effect is applied to the body, but not to the red div. Is it possible to add the bounce scrolling effect to the red div as well?

This is the code of the demo video. I'm using TailwindCSS in my project:

```html
<div class="h-screen w-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
    <div class="w-60 h-96 bg-black overflow-y-scroll overscroll-contain">
        <div class="w-full bg-red-400">
            Lorem ipsum dolor....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="fixed w-screen h-20 bottom-0 bg-slate-400" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The application of this effect is handled by your mobile browser, rather than being applied by any CSS or TailwindCSS. While you may explore ways to implement it using CSS for your particular browser, it's unlikely that such a solution exists. And even if it did, cross-browser compatibility would likely be a challenge.